# Условие If и "var1 cannot be resolved to a variable" in Java Eclipse, где ошибка?

Tags: java, eclipse, if, variable

Написал точный пример из книги, но у меня выдает ошибку почему-то.

```
public class Bit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                var1 = 99;
                if (var1 < 100)System.out.println("Ja");
                if (var1 > 100)System.out.println("Nein");
                if (99 > 100)System.out.println("Nie");

            }
    }
```

Выдает:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    var1 cannot be resolved to a variable
    var1 cannot be resolved to a variable
    var1 cannot be resolved to a variable

```
at Bit.main(Bit.java:6)
```

Comment: 99% современных IDE видят такие ошибки ещё до компиляции. Стоит задуматься

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int var1 = 99;
        if (var1 < 100)System.out.println("Ja");
        if (var1 > 100)System.out.println("Nein");
        if (99 > 100)System.out.println("Nie");

    }
}
```

Вы не указали тип переменной var1

Answer (score -1):

Вы не указали тип переменной `var1`. Укажите тип и, я думаю, всё заработает.

Например:

```
{
.....
int var1 = 99;
.....
}
```